# Clean URLs don’t work after upgrade

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I recently upgraded my CodeIgniter app from v1.7.2 to 2.0.2.

I use mod_rewrite to produce clean URLs without index.php e.g. `example.com/controller/action`. It is working on my local dev server but when I updated my production app all requests to `example.com/controller/action` result in displaying main page (i.e. index.php).

When I access address like that: `example.com/index.php/controller/action` it works.

Mod_rewrite is on as it was working fine with previous code version. With 1.7.2 I used `$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"` but now I switched to `"PATH_INFO"` because auto resulted in 404.

Because it is working on dev I’m wondering if I missed any deployment step. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are .htaccess rules I'm using with CI 2:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #paths that you don't want to rewrite
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|session|robots\.txt) 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: My .htaccess is very similar. I don't think this is .htaccess problem as it was working before and I didn't change that file when upgrading the code

Comment: Have you followed these how to's?  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_200.html  ,  http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/05/upgrading-to-codeigniter-2.0

Comment: I have followed the tutorials and on dev it's working. Just wondering what's wrong with my production env

Answer (score 0):

I think I had some similar problem and I believe it got resolved by changing permission on my root folder to 777... but that was on XAMPP